# Retrieve list of top 100 users on Stack Overflow sorted by posted content?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I am trying to replicate the top user page with the users sorted by number of posts.

Suppose there are two users:

User 'A' with 5608 post (Answers + questions) And User 'B' with 2627 post(Answers + question). The query results should be:

```
List 
User A
User B
```

So far I have written a query to list the top 100 users with the most posts (answers and questions). The query is below:

```
Select Top 100 
       OwnerUserId as [User Link]
       , sum(score) score
       , count(*) [# posts]
       , sum(case posttypeid when 1 then score else 0 end) [question score]
       , sum(case posttypeid when 2 then score else 0 end) [answer score]
       , sum(case posttypeid when 1 then 1 else 0 end) [# questions]
       , sum(case posttypeid when 2 then 1 else 0 end) [# answers]
from Posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)

WHERE 
 owneruserid is not null
and posttypeid in (1,2) -- only questions and answers
and communityowneddate is null
group by owneruserid    
order by sum(score) desc
```

This query is sorting results incorrectly. It shows:

```
2. BalusC (Post 17035 post)

3. Darin Dimitrov (post 21486)
```

The one with more posts is at the third rank. I could not figure out what is wrong, and could not write a correct query for it.

I have referred to these posts:

- [Retrieve list of top user tags on data.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325827/retrieve-list-of-top-user-tags-on-data-stackexchange-com)
- [Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408866/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-where)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the join with `PostTags` causes posts to count multiple times, depending on how many tags they have.

Also, you're ordering by `sum(score) desc` - that's the total *score* of the posts. If you want to order by the # of posts, just order by `count(*) desc`, like [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1046442).

[image]

Comment: You query show jon skeet has 99031 post but he has answered 34695 answers and asked 50 questions. @Glorfindel

Comment: That's because you're joining with PostTags, which isn't necessary here. I'll modify the query ...

Comment: Have you edited your query so that jon skeet's total post should be Answres plus question = 34745 (50q + 34 695 A). Right now query gave Jon skeet's post = 34592 @Golrfindel

Comment: **Your** query (not mine, I just copied it) excludes Community Wiki posts, because of this clause: `and communityowneddate is null`.

Comment: (also, SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, so this week's posts aren't reflected in the query results)

Comment: I removed community null part and ran query it gave 34735 but it should be 34745 there is a difference of 10 post why? https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1046443   @glorfindel

Comment: See my previous comment ...

Comment: How can i contact you? @Glorfindel my email is whatisimp4u@gmail.com please send me your email. I never spam or misuse email